# IE11 SCRIPT1002 syntax error with => in main.js babel and webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I am getting error `SCRIPT1002 syntax error` in IE11 with ES6 and Babel.

I found that it is due to arrow function `=>` in my typescript code.

I am using

- Vue
- webpack: "^4.20.2",
- @babel/core: "^7.1.2"`

I've tried following `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [ "> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8" ]
        },
        "useBuiltIns": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `transform-es2015-arrow-functions` babel plugin. If you will still experience similar errors - try to analyze the code of your bundle and find which [ES6 feature not supported by IE11](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) remain there and add plugins for them.

Comment: It worked by changing "module" value in tsconfig.json file
"module": "esnext"